# How do I fix this error: ValueError: cannot determine region size; use 4-item box?

Tags: python, image

Im writing a script that takes 10k images from a folder and collages them into rows of 100.
Each image is 32x32 pixels.
This is the script I wrote:

```
import glob
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

#creates an Image based on given pixel size
collage = Image.new("RGBA", (3200,3200), color=(255,255,255,255))
images = glob.glob("*.png")
for image in images:
    img = Image.open(image)
    x = img.convert("RGBA")
    print(x)
#takes each image from the given directory above and merges it into a collage
for i in range(0,3200,32):
    for j in range(0,3200,32):
        img = images.pop()
        collage.paste(img, (i,j))

#displays output of collage
collage.show()

#saves Image to given directory
collage.save(r"C:\Users\17379\Desktop\Nouns DAO\Noun assets\noun"+image)
```

But when I run it, I get this error:

```
ValueError: cannot determine region size; use 4-item box
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You get that error where, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

`images` is a list of file names.  You do load them in your first loop, but you never save the images anywhere -- you throw them away.  Thus, in your second loop, you are passing a file name to `collage.paste`, not an image object.

Maybe:

```
images = glob.glob("*.png")
images = [Image.open(image).convert("RGBA") for image in images]
for i in range(0,3200,32):
    for j in range(0,3200,32):
        img = images.pop()
        collage.paste(img, (i,j))
```

Also remember that `.pop()` pops from the end.  If you want the images in order, you need `.pop(0)`.

Comment: I tried this and It gives me another error:
`    img = images.pop(0)
IndexError: pop from empty list
`

Comment: That means you have less than 10,000 image files.